# Automatically Copy Data and Use Cell A1 As Range Reference in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Good day. I hope you guys are doing well.

I am just new in Google sheet and I badly need your help. I normally used the sample/lines below in MS Excel to automatically copy the formula from Cell C2:D2 to Cell C3:D6 and then convert it to values. I also used Cell A1 as a reference to the range so it will know to copy the formula until row 6.

**Problem:** I don't know how to do the same thing in Google sheet since the script is different from MS Excel VBA.

This line below is the sample script that I am using in Excel VBA and I don't know how to do the same thing in Google sheet:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

x = Range("A1").Value

Range("C2:D2").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("C3:D" & x).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("C3:D" & x).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False"
```

Please see image below for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve a value from cell "A1" as the last row number. And, you want to copy the formulas of "C2:D2" to "C3:D". In this case, you want to copy the formulas by using the last row number retrieved from "A1" for "C3:D".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set your sheet name. And save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const row = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheet.getRange("C2:D2").copyTo(sheet.getRange(`C3:D` + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
}
```

- When this script is run, the above process is run.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean))

Comment: Good day. I hope you are doing well. Now I want to copy Cell C3:D6 and then paste it into Values. I tried this line but it is not working.


sheet.getRange("C3:D6").copyTo(sheet.getRange(`C3:D` + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

Comment: @Poch About your new question of `Now I want to copy Cell C3:D6 and then paste it into Values. I tried this line but it is not working. sheet.getRange("C3:D6").copyTo(sheet.getRange(C3:D + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)`, w question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Poch Thank you for replying. It't no problem. I would like to continue to support you.

Comment: Moving forward I'll post it as a Question and not a Comment. 

Do you have any idea what code should I use to copy Cell C3:D6 and paste it as values?


```sheet.getRange("C3:D6").copyTo(sheet.getRange(C3:D + row), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)```

Comment: @Poch Thank you for replying. When I saw your posted new question, I wouldl like to check it.